# How to use window event in parent React JSX window with Child JSP window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsp

In one of the scenario I am redirecting an external JSP in a new window, keeping the source window open.

An event is triggering from JSP Page side which I am not able to read in React screen. In this scenario React screen is Parent window and JSP screen is Child window. As per the documentation in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event , I would be able to communicate between the parent and child window.

This is working in case where the parent and child window are in JSP, but in this case where parent is react screen and child window is in JSP it seems not be capturing. Although I am using the same syntax in both the case.
Below is the snippet for the Parent React and Child JSP. Am I missing some syntax or should it work in this case ?

Could anyone suggest or guide me through this issue.

```
    //Calling the external url
    
    var w=window.open("","","location=no,menubar=no,width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes")
    w.location("jsp_Page_URL")

//capturing the event from jsp
 
    onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log("INSIDE event", event)        

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The w.location("jsp_Page_URL") line is incorrect. To set the location of the child window, you should use w.location.href = "jsp_Page_URL".

Ensure that the postMessage method is used in the child window (JSP) to send messages to the parent window (React).

In the parent React window:

```
// Open the child window and set its location
var w = window.open("", "", "location=no,menubar=no,width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes");
w.location.href = "jsp_Page_URL";

// Listen for messages from the child window
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    console.log("Received message in React:", event.data);
});
```

In the parent React window:

```
// Send a message to the parent window
window.opener.postMessage("Hello from JSP", "*");
```